# logging to oracle with nLog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, logging, odp.net, nlog

I'm making MVC web application with ODP.net and trying to log to Oracle 11g with nLog 3.1, but keep failing. Of course, the insert query works fine, I tested it.

The exception which I get is below.

```
[ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.set_CommandType(CommandType value) +119
   NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo logEvent) +120
   NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) +133
   NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +46

[NLogRuntimeException: Exception occurred in NLog]
   NLog.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Write>b__0(Exception ex) +79
   NLog.Internal.SingleCallContinuation.Function(Exception exception) +90
   NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +93
   NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +218
   NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(TargetWithFilterChain targetListHead, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException) +168
   NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory) +181
   NLog.Logger.WriteToTargets(LogLevel level, IFormatProvider formatProvider, T value) +61
   NLog.Logger.Info(String message) +25
   MyProject.LogHelper.Info(String message) in C:\MyProject\LogHelper.cs:79
   MyProject.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\MyProject\Global.asax.cs:45

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception occurred in NLog]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9936485
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception occurred in NLog]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

And the configuration which I'm using is below.

```
<nlog autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

   <!-- 
   See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
   for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->

<targets>
    <!-- add your targets here -->
    <target name="LogFile" xsi:type="File" keepFileOpen="true"
            fileName="${basedir}/../TempData/Log/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${newline} ${message} ${newline}"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/../TempData/Log/${shortdate}/$backup_{##}.log" archiveAboveSize="10485760" maxArchiveFiles="10" archiveNumbering="Sequence" />

    <target name="LogDatabase" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="false" useTransactions="true"
            dbProvider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
            connectionString="data source=_tnsname; user id=_userid; password=_password; Validate Connection=true"
            commandText="insert into DBOWNER.LOGTABLE(LOG_LOGID, LOG_MESSAGE) values(DBOWNER.SEQ.nextval, :LOG_MESSAGE)">
        <parameter name="LOG_MESSAGE" layout="${message}" />
    </target>
</targets>

<rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="LogFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="LogDatabase" />
</rules>
```

Please anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem.

The reason was wrong default value of commandType. By the unknown reason, initial value of commandType was assigned as 0, despite its default value is 1(COMMANDTYPE.TEXT) by the code(https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/DatabaseTarget.cs)

Anyway I modified my configuration to set the commandType as 'Text'. And it works fine now.

```
<target name="LogDatabase" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="false" useTransactions="true"
            dbProvider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
            connectionString="data source=_tnsname; user id=_userid; password=_password; Validate Connection=true"
            commandText="insert into dbowner.LOGTABLE(LOG_LOGID, LOG_LEVEL, LOG_MESSAGE, LOG_TAG, LOG_CALLSITE, LOG_CREATEDTIME) values(dbowner.SEQ.nextval, :LOG_LEVEL, :LOG_MESSAGE, :LOG_TAG, :LOG_CALLSITE, sysdate)"
            commandType="Text" >
```